# Recommended ratios for SGA and PGA size in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I want to change the size of my SGA parameters SGA_MAX_SIZE and SGA_TARGET. And PGA  _AGGREGATE_TARGET, what will be the ratio I should adopt to set these parameters in 11g.
My current database parameters size are;

sga_max_size                         big integer 15G
sga_target                           big integer 13G
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 900M

Thanks

Comment: your question is really too generic. The first informations to use as starting point to verify the setting of such parameters are select from  v$pga_target_advice and select from v$sga_target_advice;

Comment: query data is too big for pasting in comment box.....but thanks I read the full details of these queries and understand the recommendation of these queries.